# jQueryrotate if else loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to setup an element that will rotate 180 degrees when clicked and then back again when clicked again. The code I am using is as follows. Is obviously not right and feels like I need to use a for loop.

```
$('#hodgepodge').click(function(){
    var i = 0;
    if (i < 1) {
        $('#hodgepodge').rotate(180);
        var i = 1;
    } else {
        $('#hodgepodge').rotate(0);
        var i = 0;
    }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to do i++ instead of the var i = method also and neither work. Feels like this should work and if I set the 1 to 0 in the if statement it fires the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `data()` to keep track of the state, and then just toggle it :

```
$('#hodgepodge').on('click', function(){
    $(this).rotate( !$(this).data('state') ? 180 : 0 );
    $(this).data('state', !$(this).data('state'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ6cc/)

Comment: Mind blown, didn't know about state before this. Thank you so much for the help works great!

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize before `click` event like

```
var i = 0;
$('#hodgepodge').click(function(){
    if (i < 1) {
        $('#hodgepodge').rotate(180);
        i = 1;
    } else {
        $('#hodgepodge').rotate(0);
        i = 0;
    }
});
```